# Transformation of data across the whole collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are currently using CosmosDB in a production environment. The scenario arises where we want to update the contents of a particular property in nearly all documents of a collection. The property is used as a lookup/search field so gradually modifying the contents of the documents upon accessing it would not be an option here.

The example document below uses the "key" property as the main lookup field. From this field, the punctuation should be removed.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "key": "123.123.123",
  ...
}
```

What would be a proper solution in this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL API in Cosmos DB, at least as of now partial updates to a document are not allowed.

Thus your approach would be to fetch the documents, make the necessary changes in the document and update that document. If you use .Net SDK, then you can update them in batches for faster updation.